# change line looks like an arrow- c++ builder borland

Tags: c++, winapi, line, draw, arrows

Is there any way on c++ builder borland (bcb6) to change the line looks like an arrow?

I have coordinate system and I am draw a line using MoveTo and LineTo methods from 0,0 to x,y while x,y are integers.

I wish this line will looks like an arrow- any ideas for it?

Comment: This is not related to borland at all, but rather to winapi.

Answer (score 1):

There are some references over the web to the undocumented function [`GdipSetPenEndCap`](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d0/de4/dll_2win32_2gdiplus_2pen_8c_ac8e570f42f6ddfa4eaacaeeeea5454ba.html), but I think your best option is to manually draw the end point of the arrow (using for example [`Polyline`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162815(v=vs.85).aspx), [`Pie`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162799(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`Polygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162814(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! assume I draw the line from (x',y') to (x,y) and I want it will looks like an arrow so I want to add the head of the arrow, so I need to add points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)- how to express x1,y1,x2,y2 on based of my givens (means, based on x',y',x,y)

Comment: For example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3274/Drawing-Arrows has some convenient formulas

Comment: do you know what exactly the code expected in First param in ArrowTo method (HDC hDC) because I passed it Canvas->Handle and it failed in linker stage, and in their code example they passed dc.m_hDC while dc is type of CPaintDC